# How to set TwwDBEdit input index?

Tags: delphi

I have a program for touch screen PC to select item. (it have no keyboard)

I want to do this: 
1. User click the type button, the type code(such as CD) will show in the TwwDBEdit.
2. User should use the number pad in my program to input the full item code(such as CD2800) 3. press enter, it will search the item and show detail.

But I have a problem at 2. , I have successfully show the item type code in TwwDBEdit but when I want to input the full item code. I see it will like this "2800CD". It should be "CD2800".

How can I set the input index?

My code is like this:

```
procedure TFrmSalesEntryTS.BtnFuncOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  type:String;
begin
  type := /*get type code from database*/
  wwDBEdit.Text := type;
end;
```

And the number pad only use the PostMessage function to send the number text to TwwDBEdit

Comment: You could easily solve this by making sure that your function `/*get type code from database*/` returns the correct value.  Are you not overthinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the cursor is remaining at the start of the control after you have programmatically set the text. You can solve this in one of two ways :-

1. After setting the text in your edit, use `wwDBEdit1.SelStart := Length(wwDBEdit1.Text);`
2. In your numeric keypad button press send a `EM_SETSEL` message to the edit to move the cursor to the end.